# Which value is bigger in $E(x)=\left|-\frac{(0.03)^3(6x^2-2)}{3!(1+x^2)^3}\right|$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$E(x)=\left|-\frac{(0.03)^3(6x^2-2)}{3!(1+x^2)^3}\right|$$

Now I want to know which one is bigger: $E(1)$ or $E(0.97)$?

If I am not allowed to simply fill in the values: is there a simple way to just "see" which one is bigger?

For context: I am trying to approximate $\arctan(0.97)$ with the use of a second order Taylor Polynomial about $1$.

By the way; $E(1)>E(0.97)$ check Wolfram Alpha: [x=1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=evaluate%20((3%2F100)%5E3%20(6%20s%5E2%20-%202))%2F(6%20(1%20%2B%20s%5E2)%5E3)%20at%20s%3D1) and [x=0.97](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=evaluate%20((3%2F100)%5E3%20(6%20s%5E2%20-%202))%2F(6%20(1%20%2B%20s%5E2)%5E3)%20at%20s%3D0.97)

Answer (score 1):

The two constants, $(0.03)^3$ and $3!$ don't matter for the absolute value. Note how $|x|=|-x|$. Rewrite:
$$E(x)=\dfrac{(0.03)^3}{3!}\left|\dfrac{6x^2-2}{(1+x^2)^3}\right|$$
This function can't be lower than $0$, but can equal $0$ at $x=0$. For $|x|>\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ we can remove the absolute value. we obtain:
$$E(x)=\dfrac{(0.03)^3}{3!}\dfrac{6x^2-2}{(1+x^2)^3}$$
and:
$$E'(x)=-\dfrac{24\cdot(0.03)^3}{3!}\dfrac{x^2-1}{(x^2+1)^4}$$
notice for $x,y\geq1$ we have $x>y\implies E(x)<E(y)$ and for $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}<x,y\leq1$ we have $x>y\implies E(x)>E(y)$ with a maximum at $E(1)$. Since $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}<0.97<1$ we have $E(0.97)<E(1)$

Comment: $E(1)$ should be bigger then $E(0.97)$

Comment: oh, wait I forgot a negative sign in the derivative. one moment please.

Comment: That is very rough calculation. Probably wrong.

Comment: @ImreVégh better this way?

Comment: @TakahiroWaki It was just to show I got a different result. I've corrected my answer, though.

Comment: @Mastrem: I apologize for the needless editing of your answer, but I had downvoted your post by mistake, and the only way to retract my vote was to perform some edit of your post first.

Comment: @KitterCatter,Mastrem see log.